# Why use React.memo() if React already uses Virtual DOM concept?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am beginner in React JS. I came across `React.memo()` a HOC component that basically only re-renders the component if the component execution results are different from its previous result which it memonizes. But why do we need to use it if there is already a concept of Virtual DOM?
Like doesn't the Virtual DOM concept also do the same thing that is not re-rendering the component if the resultant virtual DOM is the same as the main DOM?
If I get it correctly aren't both follow same concept functionality wise?

Comment: "*Doesn't the Virtual DOM concept also do the same thing that is not re-rendering the component if the resultant virtual DOM is the same*" - well, it could, but React was too dumb to pull it off. It always re-renders all child components, unless you explicitly tell it not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it's own - yes, *similar* to Virtual DOM. But from [documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo):

> [The `memo()`] component will usually not be re-rendered when its parent component is re-rendered. […] memoization is only a performance optimization. […] React normally re-renders a component whenever its parent re-renders.

So in other words you can use `React.memo()` to optimize component if you know that even if parent has changed, this component will not change.

Comment: So basically if we use React.memo() then the child component will not be re-rendered if there is no change in props, if the parent component re-renders. Meanwhile, if we do not use it then the child component is also re-rendered if the parent component is rendered even if there is no change in props of the child component. Also, React.memo() only checks props and not the state of the component. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That understanding sounds very correct to me :)

Answer (score 2):

React rendering happens at multiple levels. The virtual DOM kicks in at React<->Browser, but using `React.memo()` can reduce the amount of times that your React code needs to be run. In short:

Virtual DOM: Reduces HTML element creation/edits

`React.memo()`: Reduce React component re-renders (before even touching HTML)

Comment: So what you meant to say is React. memo() doesn't even need to create a Virtual DOM and compares the results of the component to it's previous state without the creation of virtual DOM?

Comment: @VipulPrakash No. It compares the props, not the results of rendering the component. It doesn't know about the component's state.

Comment: So basically if we use React.memo() then the child component will not be re-rendered if there is no change in props and if the parent component re-renders. Meanwhile, if we do not use it then the child component is also re-rendered if the parent component is rendered. Also, React.memo() only checks props and not the state of the component. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: React.memo() saves the child component from being re-rendered (from React's perspective). Even if you don't use React.memo(), React's virtual DOM will eventually (upon flush) realize that nothing is changed, and won't bother firing an update.But is has wasted some (purely JS) work already.

Comment: And yes state isn't a factor here because it's self controlled. When a component's state changes, its parents don't care at all.

Answer (score 0):

React will execute your function component, compare it to the dom and will update if there are changes. If you use `React.memo()` your function component will not be executed again and it won't be compared to the dom.

So if you have a calculation in your function compoent that takes one second, without `React.memo()` it will run this calculation again.